# Prove all base 10 positive integers are divisible by 3 if the sum of their digits is divisible by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across a strange property of $3$ in base $10$; for all integers I have tried, the following rule seems to be true:

> The integer '$n$' is divisible by $3$ if the sum of the digits of the integer are also divisible by three.

Is there a proof to show that this in fact is true? Or a counter example to disprove?

**An example of the rule:**

Suppose '$n$' = $123456789$.

Then
$$ 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45 $$
$$ 4+5 = 9 $$
$$ 9 \mod 3 = 0 $$
Therefore

$$ 123456789 \mod 3 = 0 $$

---

Afterword: For those of you who are wondering, I realized this rule while working on a database where every third row had a value I was wanted. What I wanted was a way to determine if a given row number '$n$' was divisible by $3$ without actually performing the function $n/3 = 0?$ and so far the rule I came up hasn't failed.

Comment: If someone is a moderator (or has mod privileges, my question is clearly a duplicate of both http://math.stackexchange.com/q/341202/89554 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/375406/89554 ). Sorry about that.